# Error in Calculating Date Difference in Days in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I'm kind of stuck in calculating difference between two dates in XSLT.

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LIST>
    <OUTPUT>
        <LOG>
            <item>
                <DocNo>123456789</DocNo>
                <CreationDate>2018-05-22</CreationDate>
            </item>
            <item>
                <DocNo>111222333</DocNo>
                <CreationDate>2018-05-24</CreationDate>
            </item>
        </LOG>
    </OUTPUT>
</LIST>
```

My XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xalan" version="2.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Rowsets>
            <Rowset Name="Bulk">
                <xsl:for-each select="LIST/OUTPUT/LOG/item">
                    <Row>
                        <DocumentNo>
                            <xsl:value-of select="DocNo"/>
                        </DocumentNo>
                        <CreationDate>
                            <xsl:value-of select="CreationDate"/>
                        </CreationDate>
                        <DateDiff>
                            <xsl:value-of select="days-from-duration(xs:date(CreationDate) - xs:date('2018-05-24'))"/>
                        </DateDiff>
                    </Row>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </Rowset>
        </Rowsets>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now when I run this XML & XSLT [here](http://xsltransform.net/ei5Pwjg) , it works fine and gives me proper output.

But now when I store this XSLT and XML in SAP MII and run it XSLT Transformation Action block, I get below error:

> Uncaught exception from XSL_Transformation_0, while trying to invoke the method javax.xml.transform.Transformer.transform(javax.xml.transform.Source, javax.xml.transform.Result) of a null object loaded from local variable 'processor'

I am really not sure what's going on. Does anyone has a clue?

Thanks

Comment: What version of XSLT does _SAP MII XSLT Transformation Action_ support? Your stylesheet works only in XSLT 2.0

Answer (score 0):

Based on your inclusion of the `xalan` namespace (unnecessary for your stylesheet) I presume that *SAP MII XSLT Transformation Action* is using Xalan as its transformer.

It appears Xalan is XSLT 1.0 only.  When I run your transform in Oxygen/XML using Xalan I get:

```
Severity: fatal
Description: Could not find function: days-from-duration
Start location: 15:119

Severity: fatal
Description: function token not found.
Start location: 15:119

Severity: fatal
Description: java.lang.NullPointerException - null
```

When I run with an XSLT 2.0 transformer it works just fine.

Comment: Do you have any method to modify above XSLT so that it can run on XSLT 1.0